# httpOnly cookies with React and Node

Tags: node.js, reactjs, security, xss, csrf

I'm trying to figure out how to implement authentication/authorization with React and Node, using httpOnly cookies, with scalability optionality. I've read JWT can solve this by using refresh tokens and httpOnly cookies.

1. The number one problem for me is how to make it work the right way with react, because the httOnly cookie isn't accessible via JS.
2. The second thing is, I want my frontend and backend to live in separated, dockerized containers, but as far as I got it, the httpOnly cookies are added to the headers only for the same domain(and same port).***Update** Actually, I've just read this is not true and I can use httpOnly cookie on same host, but different ports.***Update2**, I've remembered what it was about: the "SameSite" property on the cookie. This will bind the cookie to the same origin, meaning port difference will consider as different origin and the cookie will not be transferred.

Can you please clarify this and maybe explain, does it really so important, I mean am I really will be in danger if I want to use some super-ultra-highly-secure website and yet, will use JWT with local storage(but with refresh tokens)? Does the httpOnly(and sameSite: true) cookies really will make a difference here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In my project (which is also Node + React) I did the following:

1. For each authenticated user (username + password) I signed two tokens, an access token and a refresh token.
2. I set the refresh token in the response header using `httpOnly` attribute. beware that latest versions of browsers won't allow third party cookies (from different domains) unless you set the attributes `Secure` and `SameSite`.
3. I return the access token as my response's body

Now in the client side (your React app):

1. You will get the access token in the response body, and here you have two options. To store it in `local storage`, or in memory. I chose to keep the token in memory instead  because of a XSS vulnerability. (This obviously requires you to get another access token on each page refresh since the memory is cleared)
2. The refresh token is not accessible through JS you are right, but you don't need it. This token will be sent on each request, and usually it's expiration date should be a long one (I set it to 6-12 months)
3. Every time you want to gain a new access token (because it's expiration time should be
   a small one, about 15-20 minutes), you will send a request to the server to "refresh" your access token, and the server will just check if the refresh token exists in the request headers, if not return a status of `Unauthorized`

EDIT: jwt tokens are not "secure" or "not secure", they are just tokens containing some data, and they allow you to make your authentication processs stateless (instead of managing sessions in your server). As long as you don't store any sensitive data in them, and sign them with a secret key that only you possess, you should be fine

EDIT 2: Since you are using react which "sanitizes" the DOM, a possibility of XSS is a minor one, so using local storage is ok and lots of websites do it. But because there is still a possibility (of you or a client injecting a script to some input element), I decided to store the access token in memory, which is a bit of a overhead but I prefer that.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help and sharing your approach to the problem, however, I don't think this is the right way to go for many reasons... For example, what makes you think the in-memory is more secure than local storage? Potential hacker can access it the same way it can access the local storage... Also, making Refresh token for such a long period of time is pointless, you lose the whole point of making them in the first place, as they're present to make sure of invalidity of the regular token, but you solve this with implementation of another potentially "lost" token. Nonsense.

Comment: local storage is more vulnerable because anyone can access it (```window.localstorage```). The advantage of storing it in memory is that there is a smaller chance of accessing your js variables that usually live in a function scope (especially in react). Regarding the refresh token strategy, this is how you use them. They have such long time for a reason, to refresh your access token. the 6-12 months expiration date is optional. If you take a look at Google OAuth2 service, their refresh tokens NEVER expire. access token on the other hand should be valid for a short time in case of stealing.

Comment: Here's a good [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Z57Ss_uiuc)  of how refresh tokens are used for authentication